# Image compression with Huffman coding

Tags: python, compression, huffman-code, image-compression, lossless-compression

I used Huffman coding in python to compress an image. After that, I found that the image size is 318 KB and the compressed file size is 107,551 KB in my PC (attached image).
I want to know that, "Is the image size correct or not?". In other word, when we are talking about an image size in a PC, how can we get the corresponding size?
If we see the image that attached, therefore, my compression algorithm has a problem, right?
because in attached image the image size is 318 KB and compressed file is 107,551 KB.

[Original image and compressed file size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkrmf.png)

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGv6p.jpg)

This is my code below:

```
path = input('Enter image path:')

image = np.asarray(Image.open(path))

pixels = []

    for row in image:

      for ch in row:

        for pix in ch:

            pixels.append(pix)

    class Node:

        def __init__(self, prob, symbol, left=None, right=None):
            # probability of symbol
            self.prob = prob

            # symbol 
            self.symbol = symbol
  
            # left node
            self.left = left

            # right node
            self.right = right

            # tree direction (0/1)
            self.code = ''

""" A function to print the codes of symbols by traveling Huffman Tree"""

    codes = dict()

    def Calculate_Codes(node, val=''):
        # huffman code for current node
        newVal = val + str(node.code)

        if(node.left):
           Calculate_Codes(node.left, newVal)
        if(node.right):
           Calculate_Codes(node.right, newVal)

        if(not node.left and not node.right):
           codes[node.symbol] = newVal
         
        return codes        

""" A  function to get the probabilities of symbols in given data"""

    def Calculate_Probability(data):
        symbols = dict()
        for element in data:
            if symbols.get(element) == None:
               symbols[element] = 1
            else: 
               symbols[element] += 1     
        return symbols

""" A function to obtain the encoded output"""

    def Output_Encoded(data, coding):
        encoding_output = []
        for c in data:
        #  print(coding[c], end = '')
        encoding_output.append(coding[c])
        
        string = ''.join([str(item) for item in encoding_output])    
        return string
        
""" A function to calculate the space difference between compressed and non compressed data"""    

    def Total_Gain(data, coding):
         before_compression = len(data) * 8 # total bit space to stor              the data before compression
         after_compression = 0
         symbols = coding.keys()
         for symbol in symbols:
         count = data.count(symbol)
         after_compression += count * len(coding[symbol]) #calculate how  many bit is required for that symbol in total
         print("Space usage before compression (in bits):", before_compression)    
         print("Space usage after compression (in bits):",    after_compression)           

    def Huffman_Encoding(data):
        symbol_with_probs = Calculate_Probability(data)
        symbols = symbol_with_probs.keys()
        probabilities = symbol_with_probs.values()
        print("symbols: ", symbols)
        print("probabilities: ", probabilities)
    
        nodes = []
    
        # converting symbols and probabilities into huffman tree nodes
        for symbol in symbols:
            nodes.append(Node(symbol_with_probs.get(symbol), symbol))
    
        while len(nodes) > 1:
              # sort all the nodes in ascending order based on their probability
              nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x.prob)
              # for node in nodes:  
        #     print(node.symbol, node.prob)
    
        # pick 2 smallest nodes
              right = nodes[0]
              left = nodes[1]
    
              left.code = 0
              right.code = 1
    
        # combine the 2 smallest nodes to create new node
              newNode = Node(left.prob+right.prob, left.symbol+right.symbol, left, right)
    
              nodes.remove(left)
              nodes.remove(right)
              nodes.append(newNode)
            
        huffman_encoding = Calculate_Codes(nodes[0])
        print("symbols with codes", huffman_encoding)
        Total_Gain(data, huffman_encoding)
        encoded_output = Output_Encoded(data,huffman_encoding)
        return encoded_output, nodes[0] 

   encoding, tree = Huffman_Encoding(pixels)

   file = open('compressed.txt','w')

   file.write(encoding)

   file.close()
```

Comment: A _big_ problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to compressed an RGB image by Huffman coding but I can not understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I attached the image to be encoded and my code. Can you check that, please?

Comment: Huffman can be good for image with constans colors (ie. figures, white screen with black text). For photos better is JPG. Write it as PNG and it will be also much bigger than JPG (I got png with size ~1.6MB). And you should compare it uncompressed size - `width * height * 3` ( for `RGB`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is already efficiently compressed as a JPEG. Any lossless compression will end up with a larger result.

Upon loading the image, the decompression takes it from 0.3 MB to 6.6 MB, right off the bat. What you are writing out is eight times the size of your generated bits, since you are writing a `0` character for a 0 bit, and a `1` character for a 1 bit. So now we're at an expansion factor of 53 to about 17 MB.

I didn't try to look at what you're doing between those two, which is apparently your attempt at Huffman coding, but your result is 46 MB. So there is another factor of three expansion in there somewhere.

Expanding by a factor of 150 is not exactly what I'd call compression.

Comment: Thanks. I have some questions. 1) After performing the compression algorithm on an image, what should we save to decompress? 2) In which format should the coded information be saved?

Comment: 1) The Huffman code + the encoded data. 2) Binary. Encode eight bits into each byte that you write.

Comment: For my second question, what I mean is we have to save the encoded data in a txt file or not? If not, which format we have to use after compression for saving the encoded data

Comment: A file is a file. It doesn't matter what you call it.  A file is a sequence of bytes.